# Monterey: mirror iPad screen on Mac in separate window

Tags: ipad, wifi, airplay, quicktime

It seems that now it is possible to mirror an iPad/iPhone screen on your mac over wifi connection. However, if you do this, you cannot do anything esle on your mac, just watch the screen. My question is whether it is possible to mirror the screen in a separate window.

Up until now, I did it by connecting iPad through a cable, opening QuickTime player, selecting New movie recording, and selecting iPad. This did the job. The advantage is that I can share screen of my mac in an online conference and I can show my iPad screen next to something else. I thought that now it will be possible to do this wirelessly.

Am I just not seeing something or is it still not possible with Monterey?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of 12.0.1 macOS Monterey only supports receiving AirPlay video fullscreen (and oddly enough, it also turns every other screen that is connected black).

If you want to receive AirPlay video in a window there is 3rd party software to accomplish this (LonelyScreen, AirServer, Reflector, ...)

Comment: Reflector 4 is my favourite 3rd party app. As I am sure you are aware, 3rd party apps  allow recording  of the iPad/iPhone screen as a video - an added bonus.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I am not going to pay for some service that should be available by default. The cable solution is good enough for me since it is free.

Comment: I thought I was going crazy as I found no one else mentioning the other screens turning black. And I don't really understand why? If you move received airplay content to external display, I can swipe up with 3 fingers and it temporarily removes the black overlay in main display, so this black overlay is definitely an artificial restriction. Any remote chance you have figured out a way to not turn them black?

Comment: This this change in more recent macOS?

Answer (score 4):

The best free solution that personally works for me is. Using the [zoom](https://zoom.us/download) to share my iPad screen using iPad via AirPlay option.

This opens up a window where I can see my iPad screen over a separate window.

[image: iPad via AirPlay]

Answer (score 2):

[LetsView](https://letsview.com/mac) is the name of the app you're looking for.

It's a free alternative to the famous Reflector app.
It allows you to mirror the iPad screen on Mac in a separate window.

Personally tested with MBP M1 Pro with iPad Air (5th Gen, M1).

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit?  How does this app solve the OP's question?  Please keep in mind that *link only answers* are not considered a quality answer and is likely to get down voted and/or deleted.  Please  add some supporting details with an [edit] your question.

Comment: @Allan Added more info to the answer to show that it solves the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I like a cable from my iPhone (13 Pro) to my MacBook (M1) and the QuickTime player app because it does not entail yet another device like an iPad, and leaves the MacBook desktop available while, as noted, mirroring the phone to the MacBook occupies the desktop. (I have not tested the moving to another device option mentioned above.)

Perhaps my use case is helpful. I can set the phone in a cheap tripod and either record the phone screen plus other applications or just the phone screen for documentation using QuickTIme Player without any 3rd party solution (which in my experience entails a rat's nest of problems.) What’s more, one can use Siri and Voice Control to control the phone in all ways, not just the camera.

So, for example, if one is interested in documenting through both video and stills some artistic work in progress, one can record the screen or phone face and later save or discard the video, and use Siri to "Say cheese" to take an image at will, these images automatically propagatating to Photos and via iCloud to the laptop.

Siri does not work when the Camera app is open on the phone so one has no control over camera settings. But Voice Control comes to the rescue because it allows one to launch the Camera App and drill in to set settings like zoom and exposure and then click the photo, all with voice commands or a single custom voice command handling all settings at once.

Siri can launch and stop Voice Control and if one uses the number not names optin in Voice Control, there is no conflict with running Siri and Voice Control simultaneously.

All this without disturbing the tripod and camera. Moreover, when the camera and tripod are such that finger and eye access to the phone face and controls are inconvenient or impossible, for example when using the (good) backface camera and pointing the rear camera toward the sky to observe the bottom of something or the night sky, voice control is the only option and seeing the face of the phone mirrored on the laptop provides for interactive use when Voice Control is indicating the names or numbers one needs to say to navigate the phone's applications and menus.

One can simultaneously operate other apps like Sensor Log to record phone orientation via accelerometer and magnetometer settings. A wireless connection to the phone would be awesome but I've tried Bluetooth and wifi (won't connect iPhone and Macbook for QuickTime Player use unfortunately, no matter what I've tried thus far and there seem many threads on this issue but little convergence)